# Missing 'manifest_version' key. Its value must be an integer either 2 or 3

Tags: reactjs, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I'm try to deploy a ReactJs chrome extension on web store and I keep getting this error message "
Missing 'manifest_version' key. Its value must be an integer either 2 or 3.". I have crossed checked my manifest.json file, everything seems to be fine, however, I still get this error.

Here is my manifest.json file:
`{ "version": "1.0.0", "manifest_version": 3, "name": "Taskaid Chrome Extension", "description": "This Chrome extension helps users organize their tasks into a list", "action": { "default_popup": "js/index.html", "default_title": "Taskaid Chrome Extension" } }`

I have tried restarting the vsCode and rewriting the manifest.json file, yet to no avail.

Comment: The code is fine. Where do you see this error? Did you place manifest.json inside a sub-directory of the zip file? Does it work if you load this zip file via `Load unpacked` button in chrome://extensions page?

Comment: Yes, the error comes up whenever I want to import the zip file for deployment. Yes, I try placing the build file inside a dist folder to unpack at chrome://extensions, it doesn't seem to recognise the manifest.json

Comment: What is "import the zip file" exactly? If you packed `dist` folder inside zip, it's a mistake and you need to recreate it so that manifest.json is at the top of zip and not inside the folder.